# I have a CORS Implementation in my Spring Boot project I wanted to know is this correct way?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity https) throws Exception {


    https.headers().disable();
    https.csrf().disable();

    https.headers().cacheControl();
    https.cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
        @Override
        public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(final HttpServletRequest request) {
            return new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

I tried with above configuration and works fine 
And I also believe in Spring we have @CrossOrigin annotations at Controller level : so which is most preferable in terms of implementation

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach is fine. The thing with the annotation based ones is that they are static in nature at compile time - but that may work perfectly in your use case.

As with many things in Spring, there is more than one valid way to do things and which is "best" will depend on your situation and requirements. If you have a static well defined CORS policy then annotation based might be the most simple and least intrusive to your code base.

If you need something slightly more dynamic or flexible - perhaps based on property settings at run time. In my latest project the way I handled CORS was like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CORSProperties.class})
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CORSProperties properties;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Configuring web security....");
        http.headers()
                .and()
                .cors();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(properties.getAllowedOrigins());
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(allHttpMethods());
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(asList(CrossDomainCsrfTokenRepository.XSRF_HEADER_NAME, CONTENT_TYPE));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(asList(LOCATION, CrossDomainCsrfTokenRepository.XSRF_HEADER_NAME));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(HOURS.toSeconds(properties.getMaxAgeInHours()));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    private List<String> allHttpMethods() {
        return Stream.of(HttpMethod.values())
                .map(HttpMethod::name)
                .collect(toList());
    }

}
```

That's not to say this is necessarily the best way, but it works for me and is flexible enough.

I'd suggest you also checkout the spring boot sample: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ which shows another pattern using the web configurer adapter:

```
 @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }
```